# Best action against fake virus scammers

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, malware, anti-virus

This morning I received a notification that after visiting some adult websites, 27 viruses have infected my phone (iPhone XR with iOS 17.3), that they would destroy my SIM card and delete my contacts. (I assume to most people that would be laughable). To handle this threat I should install an app named “Spyshield” from the App Store, a link was provided and actually works.

So there is an app on the store that tries to get customers through scamming people.

I’ve sent one message to apple support. I can’t report them on the App Store because I didn’t download the app. I can’t leave a review for the same reason.

What is the best way to make their behavior uneconomical or get their app removed?

Comment: In the meantime you could try something like AdGuard [freeware] which will block a lot of the nasties before you even see them.

Answer (score 1):

> I received a notification...

No.  You received a pop up web page.  It's simply a JavaScript modal with HTML code to mimic an "alert."

> So there is an app on the store that tries to get customers through scamming people?

No.  You can't stop people from trying to scam other people.  This is where you have to realize what it is and move on through.

> What is the best way to hurt these people?

Stop going to websites where this type of attack is commonplace (i.e. adult websites)

> I’ve sent one message to apple support. I can’t report them on the App Store because I didn’t download the app. I can’t leave a review for the same reason.

The idea is for you to download the app and get you to give up tons of your personal data; you took the right step in not downloading it.

> [What's] the best action against fake virus scammers

Don't engage with them.  The less engagement, the more it fails.  The more it fails, the more likley they will abandon that attack vector.

Comment: The app in question has a subscription model. Looking at the wording in the app description, the prices most likely will be high and users will be tricked into buying an expensive subscription.